# Parallel Machine Scheduling test data

Tags: reference-request, optimization, scheduling, data-sets

I am writing optimization program for unrelated parallel machine scheduling problem on CUDA. Now, the only thing I am missing are some test cases.

Does anyone know where I can find such data? I have been searching for a while but I've only found this: http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastjjb/jeb/info.html. Unfortunately there is no test data for UPMS. 
I know I can easly generate some cases but I just wanted to be sure if optimum is being found correctly.

Comment: Can't you generate test data using a (sequential) reference implementation?

Comment: I have just finished implementing it. Thanks for suggestion